# I have a pre-processed C/C++ source file (cacti.i). How to I generate the executable binary file from this .i file, so that I can run it like ./cacti?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

The software I'm using has provided only the .i file and expects us to use it like: **run the "cacti" binary <./cacti -infile cache.cfg>**
But I don't have a binary file. It seems to me that I need to generate that from the .i file and then run the binary. How do I do this?

Comment: Something needs to be *compiled* and *linked*.

Comment: The same way as from a non-pre-processed.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ language allows overloading of functions, so there may be *name mangling* involved.  The C language won't have to mangle the names.

Comment: I'm unable to run it like gcc cacti.i
cacti.i:1:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘%’ token
 %module cacti
 ^
cacti.i:4:1: error: stray ‘#’ in program
 #include "cacti_interface.h"
 ^
cacti.i:8:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘%’ token
 %include "cacti_interface.h"

https://github.com/HewlettPackard/cacti/blob/master/cacti.i
That's the file

Comment: The project has a `makefile`, did you execute `make` to build the project?

Comment: I did try running make. It gave errors and did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `catci.i` are

```
%module cacti
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "cacti_interface.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "cacti_interface.h"
```

which is not proper C code.<sup>1</sup>

The project must be compiled with `make`:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:HewlettPackard/cacti.git
$ cd cacti
$ make
```

This will build the project and it generates the `catci` binary which you should
use.

If you don't have a github account, the the cloning like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/HewlettPackard/cacti.git
```

I've made a clone 5 minutes ago and executed `make` to test it, it compiled
without problems (I did get a few warnings though, but you don't have to worry
about them). And I was able to do

```
$ ./cacti -infile sample_config_files/ddr3_cache.cfg
```

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup>As [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759025/i-have-a-pre-processed-c-c-source-file-cacti-i-how-to-i-generate-the-execut/49759598#comment86534180_49759598) points out in the comments, this looks more like
`swig`. I've never used it, so I don't know if that's true.

Comment: that looks like swig, nothing to do with c preprocessor output

Comment: @pm100 like I said, I've never seen such a syntax, that was just a guess.

Comment: I tried running make and it gave me errors. Didn't succeed and didn't generate any binary file.

Comment: @SheetalKrishna well, without seeing what error you've got when you executed `make`, I cannot help you. It is perhaps a better idea to post an issue here https://github.com/HewlettPackard/cacti/issues  directly into the developer's site. They might help you more than we can